# Move customized django-allauth templates to directory other than 'account'

Tags: django, django-templates, django-allauth

I set up `django-allauth` correctly following the project's documentation. I wanted to override the look and feel of the `django-allauth` templates so I went to the project github and downloaded [the django-allauth templates folder](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/master/allauth/templates/account) into my `accountsapp/templates` directory.

My problem is that `django-allauth` will only look for its templates in the `templates/account` folder.

I want to put my templates in the `templates/allauth/account` folder to help keep MY template files separate from `django-allauth`'s template files.

When I do this, `django-allauth` is unable to find the templates that I customized.

Here is my project structure:

```
projectfolder/
    accountsapp/
        templates/

    projectsettings/
        settings.py
    manage.py
```

**What I've tried:**

1. Setting my `TEMPLATES` `'DIRS'` to this

   ```
   'DIRS': [ os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'accountsapp', 'templates', 'allauth'), ],
   ```

   With `BASE_DIR` being this: `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`.
   This works, but I'm not sure that this is the best practice/solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your templates in `projectfolder/accountsapp/templates/`, then the app directories loader will find them, as long as you have `'APP_DIRS': True` in your template settings.

However, if you move the templates into the `projectfolder/accountsapp/templates/allauth` subfolder, then the app directories loader will not find them, so you will have to add the directory to `DIRS` as you have already done.